# How fast is perl hash select?

Tags: perl, hash, berkeley-db

I use Perl hash to store ip -> hostname pairs. I have millions of it.

I cache gethostbyip syscall in the hash %HOSTNAME{$ip}.

Memory is not the issue. Time is.

How fast perl hash search works in this condition?

Will it work faster if I will use MysqlDB or BerkleyDB instead?

Comment: Do a benchmark.

Comment: Mysql and BerkleyDB are using external storage unlike plain hash so answer seems obvious.

Comment: You'll want `$HOSTNAME{$ip}`, not `%HOSTNAME{$ip}`.

Comment: Hash look-up in perl is blazing fast, even for quite large hashes (as far as you have the RAM to store them).

Comment: How do you use the data?  Some solutions may be better only for some "access patterns".

Comment: @salva, More precisely, hash lookup speed isn't affected by the size of the hash (O(1)).

Comment: IPv4 addresses are simply 32-bit numbers. If you're only dealing with IPv4, and if memory really isn't an issue, the fastest solution is likely an array with 4 billion elements.

Comment: @ikegami: well, in practice hash lookup speed **is** affected by the hash size because of the hierarchical memory caches.

Comment: More than any other structure? If not, I don't see the point in mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have sufficient RAM to hold all of the data, in-memory lookups will just about *always* be faster than retrieving data from an external source (disk, database, etc.) because RAM is fast and I/O operations are slow.

If you can't hold it all in RAM, then it becomes less predictable and you may need to benchmark to determine what's faster for your particular combination of program and hardware.

Comment: Does perl hash uses an index to find given key, or it scans all hash memory to find it, or perl keeps keys sorted and does binary search?

Comment: None of the above. A hash allocates a number of "buckets" and uses a hashing algorithm to distribute items between the buckets. It doesn't need to index, scan, or search because it knows which bucket an item belongs in and can go there directly - hash lookups are O(1). Of course, hash collisions are possible, in which case multiple items will be stored as a linked list within a bucket (which does need to be scanned linearly), but a good implementation (such as Perl's) will transparently increase the number of buckets before this becomes problematic.